# Problems accessing a _Thread_local variable in x86_64 asm

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, instrumentation, thread-local-storage

I my currently working on a project that involves asm x86_64 and instrumenting code. I insert asm code thru GIMPLE that allow me to access a variable by name and decrease it.  For example: `sub $%d, special_counter\n\t`.  Now the problem is that I need to make this project multithreaded and each thread needs one of this variables (they cannot be the same variable as it is a counter for each thread), not only that but I only know on what thread that code is going to run after the compilation phase.

My current approach involves the directive _Thread_local and trying to use `sub $%d, special_counter@tlsgd(%rip)\n\t` but I get this error:
`relocation R_X86_64_32S against \.text' cannot be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC` and I’m using the -fPIC flag.

So do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? (I got the `@tlsgd(%rip)` from writing a smaller program that uses a `_Thread_local` variable and examining the asm code produced)

If you have any other idea on how to approach this problem it is also welcomed.

Comment: how 'each thread needs one of this variables' is a problem? Each thread has unique ID, so you can have array of variables with elements count equal to count of your threads and translate thread ID to array index. Seems simple enough

Comment: The problem is that the instrumented code(sub $%d, special_counter\n\t) is added before I know any thread ids, so I need a way to specify were special_counter is in memory. I need an ASM compiled time solution

Comment: I guess this is for GNU/Linux based on the error message.  I tried it myself in a stand-alone `.s` file.  You need `subl` or `subq` to set an operand-size, otherwise it defaults to dword.  How did you define the `special_counter` symbol you referred to?  With just a `special_counter: .long 123` in `.data`, GAS errors about *Accessing 'special_counter' as thread-local object*.  With it undefined, *TLS transition from R_X86_64_TLSGD to R_X86_64_GOTTPOFF against `special_counter' at 0x7 in section '.text' failed*.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to use an addressing mode involving `%fs`, reserving some space in the same block where it keeps the stack canary and other per-thread things, including I think a pointer to normal TLS vars.  As a one-off hack you could skip that level of indirection.